# Biblatex/Memoize: Error if cited bib entry includes verbatim field

Tags: biblatex, errors, verbatim, compilation-error, memoize

If Biblatex is used with the current version of Memoize, citing any entry containing a verbatim field results in compilation failure. I've reported this as [a bug](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize/issues/13), but is it possible to workaround the error in the meantime? Even just something which switches memoization of Biblatex stuff off would be a useful stopgap, but I can't figure out how to do this correctly.

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoize}
\mmzset{prefix=memos/}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
  \cite{markey}
\end{document}
```

yields

```
! Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ...ldateera}{ce} \verb {urlraw} \verb h
                                                  ttp://mirror.ctan.org/info...
l.60     \endentry
                  
?
```

Similarly,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoize}
\mmzset{prefix=memos/}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
  \cite{padhye}
\end{document}
```

fails with

```
! Use of \blx@bbl@verbadd@i doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ...d {dateera}{ce} \verb {file} \verb f
                                                  tp://gaia.cs.umass.edu/pub...
l.69     \endentry
                  
?
```

Compilation sequence:

```
TEXMFHOME=/d pdflatex <filename>
TEXMFHOME=/d biber <filename>
TEXMFHOME=/d pdflatex <filename>
```

The errors occur when the generated `.bbl` is read during the second `pdflatex` run.

I've tried adding `begindocument/before/.append style={auto=\blx@bbl@entry{verbatim,outer handler=\mmz@biblatex@entry}},` to `\mmzset{}`. I've also tried `begindocument/before/.append style={auto=\blx@bbl@entry{noop}},` and redefining `\mmz@biblatex@entry`. The first two fail because `\blx@bbl@entry` isn't defined using `\NewDocumentCommand` and I can't figure out an appropriate argument specification. The third fails because I have no idea whether changes here even can make a difference, let alone which changes might make the difference I want.

Comment: You can try `\let\blx@bbl@entryORI\blx@bbl@entry
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\let\blx@bbl@entry\blx@bbl@entryORI}` (memoize stores the original too but the name of the csname is rather arkward).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, danke! That does indeed work around the problem. I can't believe it is that (relatively) simple.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So adding `\AddToHook{package/biblatex/after}{\let\blx@bbl@entry@orig\blx@bbl@entry}%
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\let\blx@bbl@entry\blx@bbl@entry@orig}%
` to `memoize.cfg` should work ;).